# Invalid auth/bad request (got a 404, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect) in magento

Tags: magento

I m Using local host server for magento rest api

Trying get product data in json format
got Invalid auth/bad request (got a 404, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirec

I also try in Browser extention it's not work